# Ajax + Flickr loading images one-by-one with fadeIn effect

Tags: jquery, ajax, flickr

i'm re-using this piece of code:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Load demo images from flickr:
    $.ajax({
        url: (window.location.protocol === 'https:' ?
                'https://secure' : 'http://api') +
                '.flickr.com/services/rest/',
        data: {
            format: 'json',
            method: 'flickr.interestingness.getList',
            api_key: ''
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
    }).done(function (result) {
        var 
            linksContainer = $('#links'),
            baseUrl;
        // Add the demo images as links with thumbnails to the page:
        $.each(result.photos.photo, function (index, photo) {
            baseUrl = 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' +
                photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret;
            $('<a/>')
                .append($('<img>').prop('src', baseUrl + '_s.jpg'))
                .hide()
                .fadeIn('slow')
                .prop('href', baseUrl + '_b.jpg')
                .prop('title', photo.title)
                .attr('data-gallery', '')
                .appendTo(linksContainer);
        });
    });
});
```

It makes his dirty job, but i have fadeIn effect ONLY with entire "wall of photo" (they are about 50), instead i would that FOR EVERY ONE SINGLE photo jquery applies fadeIn effect.

Thank you to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Load demo images from flickr:
    $.ajax({
        url: (window.location.protocol === 'https:' ?
                'https://secure' : 'http://api') +
                '.flickr.com/services/rest/',
        data: {
            format: 'json',
            method: 'flickr.interestingness.getList',
            api_key: ''
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
    }).done(function (result) {
        var 
            linksContainer = $('#links'),
            baseUrl;
        // Add the demo images as links with thumbnails to the page:
        $.each(result.photos.photo, function (index, photo) {
            baseUrl = 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' +
                photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret;
            $('<a/>')
                .append($('<img>').prop('src', baseUrl + '_s.jpg'))
                .hide()
                //.fadeIn('slow')
                .prop('href', baseUrl + '_b.jpg')
                .prop('title', photo.title)
                .attr('data-gallery', '')
                .appendTo(linksContainer);
        });

        setTimeout(function(){ showImg($('#links a:first'))}, 1000);
    });
});

function showImg(el)
{
    el.fadeIn('slow');
    if(el.next().is('a'))
    {
        setTimeout(function(){ showImg(el.next())}, 1000);
    }
}
```